# How to rotate an Info Button with the view?

Tags: iphone, sdk, orientation, landscape

I'm just trying to write a view based Application, which only uses the landscape Orientation.

Using this Code:

```
application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

in the `applicationDidFinishedLaunching` method the Application starts in landscape orientation.

The problem is, that if I create a landscape view in InterfaceBuilder, the view does not get shown up the way I created it... I need to create the view in portrait mode and imagine how it looks when it is in portrait mode (hope you understand what I mean?) - I insert already rotated images.
So, I got everything work now, but the InfoButton doesn't rotate (as the other buttons, but the others are already rotated images)...

Whats my fault? How to I tell the Application to use my View, which I designed in Landscape orientation?

Thanks so much.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You may have to rotate your view (button) dependent on orientation:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
CGAffineTransform transform;
switch (orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180*M_PI/180);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*M_PI/180);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90.0*M_PI/180);
        break;
    default:
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;
}
[[myView layer] setAffineTransform:transform];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the view in portrait mode and imagine how it looks when it is in portrait mode. Just you need to create your view in your needed mode, then set your project setting to your needed mode. In `Xcode` on the left view you can see `Project Navigator` click on the blue icon of project name. Now on the middle view (editor view) you can see the `summary` tab, on this tab set your needed mode on the `iPhone Development Orientations`.